# Using fgets with array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Hello im trying to scan a string into pointer array but its not working,
What am i doing wrong?

```
char* ptrName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
printf("Enter Player name \n");
fgets(ptrName, 20, stdin);
printf("%s", *ptrName);
```

Comment: uSEwrasd, Curious: what reference or who suggested casting the result with `(char*)` in  `(char*)malloc(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
printf("%s", *ptrName);
```

`printf("%s", …)` is expecting a string you are giving it a char.

Right:

```
printf("%s", ptrName);
```